# Maven development time and release time

Tags: eclipse, maven, version, release, snapshot

I'm starting working with **Eclipse + Maven (2.2.1)** and I have some question about it:

**1-** I have an internal framework **MyFramework** that is dependency in another project, something like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyFramework</artifactId>
    <version>[7.0.0,),[LATEST]</version>
</dependency>
```

The version is a range because I want to work with my workspace framework version, or with the latest (in case I don't have the project in workspace).
My project is building fine, but when I try to make a relase (**maven-release-plugin 2.3.2**) I got:

```
NullPointerException: version of MyFramework is null
```

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

**2-** Suppose that I have a version 7.0.4-SNAPSHOT and I want to roll the second version number instead of third like that:

```
7.0.4-SNAPSHOT -> 7.1.0-SNAPSHOT or 7.1.4-SNAPSHOT (whatever)
```

Can I do it with maven-release-plugin?

---

**3-** I'm starting with Maven, so I don't need to care about migrations, should I start with Maven 3 instead of Maven 2?

---

Please, I need help with it.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. This appears to be a known issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-318
2. Yes, every time you perform a release you can override the default version number. If you release using the command line, you will be prompted to select the next version number (with a sensible default displayed).
3. Use Maven 3. Read [this blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/02/top-ten-reasons-to-move-to-maven-3/) for a list of reasons why it is superior.

Comment: Hi Jones, thanks for helping. 1 - I read about this issue, but I through that it was corrected, because is a very old issue. Any idea what can I do about it? 2 - But by default, the plugin changes the last number no asking, I need it automatically too, but changing the second number. 3 - Thanks by tip.

Comment: Jones, I've update to Maven 3 and works fine now, apparently is a bug when running with Maven 2. Please, can you help me with my second question? Maybe using parent POM...

Comment: Which part of question two have I not answered? You can do exactly what you want to do - try it out!

Comment: I do not want to type the version, I wanna do it automatically, but change the second number of version not the third.

Comment: That sounds a very strange use case and I don't think it's automatically supported by the plugin. You can specify the next version in the command line call (`mvn -DreleaseVersion=X.Y.Z release:prepare`) but that's about it.